Why do I get a TypeError at HTMLButtonElement.onclick(Key.html:74:55)?
I am trying to generate a reordered sequence based on user inputs first name, last name, date of birth, and pin code. The sequence is combined, padded, and reordered using a specific mapping logic. Why am I getting this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')
at generateKey (Key.html:86:57) at
HTMLButtonElement.onclick(Key.html:74:55)

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Key Generator</h1>
        <form id="KeyForm">
            <label for="firstName">First Name (Max 4 characters):</label>
            <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" maxlength="20" required>

            <label for="lastName">Last Name (Max 20 characters):</label>
            <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" maxlength="20" required>

            <label for="dob">Date of Birth (MMDDYYYY):</label>
            <input type="text" id="dob" name="dob" maxlength="8" required>

            <label for="zipCode">Zip Code (5 characters):</label>
            <input type="text" id="zipCode" name="zipCode" maxlength="5" required>

            <button type="button" onclick="generateKey()"> Key</button>
        </form>

        <div id="result" class="output" style="display: none;">
            <strong>Generated Key:</strong>
            <p id="outputSequence"></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        function generateKey() {
            // Get inputs
            const firstName = document.getElementById('firstName').value.padEnd(4, '*').slice(0, 4);
            const lastName = document.getElementById('lastName').value.padEnd(20, '*').slice(0, 20);
            const dob = document.getElementById('dob').value.padEnd(8, '*').slice(0, 8);
            const zipCode = document.getElementById('zipCode').value.padEnd(5, '*').slice(0, 5);

            // Combine into one sequence
            const combinedSequence = firstName + lastName + dob + zipCode;

            // Reorder based on mapping
            const reorderMap = [
                12
            ];

            let reorderedSequence = '';
            for (const idx of reorderMap) {
                reorderedSequence += combinedSequence[idx - 1];
            }

            // Display the result
            document.getElementById('outputSequence').textContent = reorderedSequence;
            document.getElementById('result').style.display = 'block';
        }
    </script>
</body>


I can't reproduce the error with the code shown. at generateKey (Key.html:86:57) - which line of the code we are seeing, is that actually?

The error message is clearly telling you that .value of something could not be accessed. Use your browser developer tools to debug. You can put a breakpoint at the start of the generateKey function and step-by-step see which element is not found. Maybe the elements don't exist yet when your code runs. You should see this in the developer tools as well.

@PeterPointer How could the elements not exist yet? The function is called when the user clicks, which has to be after the DOM is loaded.

Check for typos in the IDs. Remember that case is significant.
